# Burninate [beta]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beta) (x250) is mostly used in connection with [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) or [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios). It does not seem useful to me for following reasons:

- Nobody can be an expert in beta
- Nobody searches for beta
- Almost all questions have an additional tag (=> easy to remove)
- 70% the questions contain "beta" in the title ([I made a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/197149/tag-occurence-in-title?TagName=beta))
- Only 2 followers

Can we burninate it? Or at least remove it from questions if we see them?

Comment: While we're at it, although `[alpha]`, `[gamma]` and `[epsilon]` seem legitimate, `[delta]` (x114) looks like a meta-tag.

Comment: @WilliamAndrewMontgomery this is my first request _today_ ;)

Comment: Why you call this a [meta-tag:feature-request]... *This tag is for proposals of new features on the site, or requests for a change to an existing feature.*?

Comment: Tag removal questions are [meta-tag:discussion] questions. We need to decide whether it's a good idea before proceeding.

Comment: Because I saw it on one of your [questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258176/remove-handling). As I've seen that you posted several burninate-request, I thought I should retag it.

Comment: @Manu - then it's the other questions that need updating

Comment: @Manu that was a mistake. I did not mean to use  that tag. I guess I was just too quick. Sorry.

Comment: Heres something to consider: So many questions are pertaining to iOS 8 and Xcode 6. These technologies are currently in beta, and many of the questions will be resolved as soon as bugs are fixed. These questions that will only pertain to the software while it is in beta could potentially be tagged as beta.

Comment: @SantaClaus: Only if you can predict exactly how the API will change in a different version before tagging the question. Even then, a version-specific tag for the actual technology you're talking about would be more useful than a generic "beta" tag.

Comment: I don't have a concrete suggestion; I'm not an iOS developer. The numeric tags for [python] seem to work well, but then we don't really get questions about RC versions and there's no "beta" per se.

Answer (score -8):

Retag them as [android-beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-beta) and [ios-beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios-beta). That would make them more relevant.

Comment: For how long, though? Until the next version is released?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it would be relevant for more than one beta version.

Comment: Well, a "beta" question for iOS 8's features might be not beta when iOS 9 is released, so it seems very time-sensitive. For what it's worth, I'm not one of the 7 people who came here to downvote this suggestion, so unfortunately my dumb comments are your only hint about why others may not like this answer. :/

Comment: @Downvoters Could you give me some reasoning? It would be deeply appreciated. It could also potentially make a compelling argument as well.