# Remove [handling]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, burninate-request

In some cases, [handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/handling) only looks useful when used with other tags. Example is [exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exception), where one should add [exception-handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exception-handling). In other cases, it should just be removed.

Comment: I am betting this is the result of people who don't know how to use the tag selector. They meant [error-handling] or [exception-handling].

Comment: This looks like a good candidate for burnination - *after* a clean up has been done. There are a bunch that are tagged `file` and `handling` that should probably be `file-io` or `file-handling`. ([This one sticks out](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22648272/109702), it is only `file` & `handling`, nothing else).

Comment: It is an empty tag, and just about every related possibility for handling in programming topics has a tag with a description. This is clearly a dangling tag that is simply waiting to be removed. Good catch.

Comment: BURRRRNINATE IT

Comment: This seems to be really common in Android questions since there is an [`android.os.Handler` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).  Is there a way to modify these questions in bulk?

Comment: @PeterGluck 10k users have the powers, with the help of some userscript.

Comment: Count for question with this tag now under 200, all questions from 2014 and 2013 are retagged. The [except] tag is maybe the next candidate for burnination.

Comment: All questions are retagged. [tag:handling] is empty.

Comment: I was fooled. I thought OP requested to remove [tag:handling] *and* [tag:on_hold]

Comment: You made a typo in the title. This must obviously be `Handle [handling]`

Answer (score 13):

I am pretty sure that there is no [handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/handling) [professional on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254313/1433392), so... let's burn it:

[image]