# Are questions still on-topic if they solely pertain to beta software and will likely become obsolete?

Tags: discussion

I answered *[How to debug iOS 8 extensions with NSLog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031612/how-to-debug-ios-8-extensions-with-nslog/24050325#24050325)*, and all of the answers there, including mine, are workarounds because of a bug in [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) 6, which is pre-release beta software. There are many other examples of this that can be found under [xcode6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode6), [ios8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios8), and a few other tags.

That question, along with all its answers, will likely become obsolete when the software is publicly released, and the bug that caused the question is fixed.

Are these questions still appropriate given that they will only be helpful for a short period of time? Once the problems that caused these questions are fixed, will it be appropriate to flag them with this?:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced
>   or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be
>   on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help
>   future readers.

---

I just came upon another question: [SourceKitService Terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24006206/2446155). It pertains to a bug in Xcode Beta. It doesn't seem to be an issue with a definitive solution, and I've found (and flagged) many duplicates of it as well. At this point it looks as if people are just guessing, there isn't much "Q and A" going on in that question.

Comment: "Are these questions still appropriate given that they will only be helpful for a short period of time?" Knowing that requires that you know the future. Professionally my work has nearly always made me live in the past. Something being obsolete does not mean it isn't being used. I feel it is more important to correctly label the questions to indicate which version of software it relates with then to be concerned if it might not relate to the current version.

Comment: There used to be a close reason for that, "Too localized" had the "limited to a specific moment in time" clause.  Not available anymore so I guess we'll have to live with them.

Comment: @DanielCook Ah - but these are being labelled with ios8 and xcode6, which will be around for a while. But they are currently beta and unreleased.

Comment: @DanielCook However, there are some questions with those tags that will never become obsolete, such as those pertaining to the new swift language, for example.

Comment: You may disagree, but I feel [this discussion about the beta tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256306/burninate-beta) is highly related.

Comment: @DanielCook I'm a step ahead of you :)

Comment: **Almost all software is at best temporary, beta software**

Comment: For almost every question you could describe a future scenario of the language/library/software in question changing, making the answer or even the question obsolete.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The community's purpose is to aid individuals with their current problem, simply ignoring it due to the fact that one day it might become obsolete will fail the purpose.

We live in a world where the technology and our tools are growing rapidly and obsolete things are simply inevitable, we shouldn't let that affect us helping others who provide good questions to their problems.

Most of the time when people come across obsolete answers it's because they did not search for the right keywords, they search was too broad or the question they found was not properly tagged (or included in the text) with the version of which they were using.

I think the browser-community is a good example here, luckily our nowadays browsers are becoming more and more alike but even so we're not sure what each and every one of them is going to support in the future. We answer questions to very specific versions of browsers, knowing that one day the answer to the question might become obsolete. But that's not really a problem if it's obvious in the question/and or the answer what version the problem is related to.

The main difference between my example and this released software is that it's less likely that people will get their hands on the old versions but as long as it's clear at what stage the software was at the time of the question we should continue answering those questions. Even if it's old it's possible that someone will be using that old version at some point and being able to stumble upon the problem and finding a solution to it is simply wonderful.

Comment: Many of the questions are caused by **bugs** that will be resolved soon in the future, and any answer would really be a workaround.

Comment: It doesn't mean that everyone will have access to the resolved versions. Some environments can be used for decades after they're considered "outdated" so the workarounds are always relevant. Your point is completely valid though, but if someone finds an old question and it's actually mentioned which version of the software is being run the one who stumbled upon that question can simply go and search elsewhere. Just because the question/answer you find doesn't fill your needs doesn't mean that it should never have taken place in the first place.

Comment: I have actually found some really useful information in some of these questions, and have answered many of them also. Everybody that has access to Xcode 6 Betas has access to Xcode 6 when it is publicly released, and there isn't any rational reason why you wouldn't start using the released version.

Comment: But of course, if something changes between now and when the software is publicly released, one could post another answer. However in many of these cases, the problem in the question wouldn't be reproducible anymore, so there wouldn't be any point in another answer.

Comment: Having a too big resource of question and answers is better than having too few. If something you find doesn't help you then simply try the next thing. If someone is too narrow-minded to be stuck with an answer, mentioned to be a problem-solver for version X, but that someone is using version X+1 then that's his problem.

Comment: Good point. These questions are plenty useful at this very moment. And I guess it doesn't really matter if they stay since if the problem really does disappear, it won't matter.

Comment: Indeed. I'm sorry if I didn't provide my point precisely enough in the answer it-self, I'll probably edit it accordingly to this conversation.

Comment: `The community's purpose is to aid individuals with their current problem.`  I think is is a nice idea and what *should* be the case, but the community's purpose is very explicitly to be a Q&A compendium for "professional and enthusiast developers" rather than helping everyone who comes along.

Comment: I agree with @JeffGohlke, except the part about "should be".

Comment: @JeffGohlke Sure but I hope that professional and enthusiast developers are considered as individual which problems' count as Q and our answers count as A. I didn't mean that we should help all individuals but rather those who meet SO's rules and standards of formatting a question. I get where you're going with this, though.

Comment: What about this example where you have to be a paying iOS developer to access the beta at all, and Apple has already acknowledged the problem in the release notes for the beta, and it's pretty much guaranteed to be fixed in the beta that comes out in the next couple of weeks? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25196782/cllocationmanager-with-swift#25196819 My feeling is the question should be closed as off topic/other *after* the bug has actually been fixed.