# Should moderators be able to vote on moderations?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, moderators

Stack Overflow is a wonderful resource but it seems the moderators get a little over-zealous sometimes.

Questions are occasionally mis-moderated. For instance, [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095677/missing-keyboard-on-ios8-simulator) was closed as off-topic but it's perfectly on topic, and it pertains directly to tools used for programming. One person's misjudgment closed it, thankfully *after* it received a good answer.

Moderations are subjective interpretations of the guidelines, and are prone to human error. Should we leverage the voting system that works so well for answers and questions against moderations?

I think it would be a very useful tool. At a certain threshold of down-votes, SO could undo the moderation and subtract rep from the moderator(s) who committed it. Conversely up-votes would add rep to the moderator(s) who committed it.

Comment: Explain your downvotes people!

Comment: What do you mean by "after they've been committed"?

Comment: @Kevin - fair point - I'll try to edit.

Comment: [Voting is different on meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta): "**On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement** with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself."

Comment: Still not sure what you mean, moderators vote on moderation things by definition, that's what they're there for.

Comment: Would be a ridiculous amount of overhead for something that's best handled using existing tools and being willing to **talk to each other**. See [Brad's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271291/should-moderators-be-able-to-vote-on-moderations/271295#271295).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let me talk about this specific case first, before addressing the more general question. The moderator's attention was drawn to this question by the fact that a flag was cast on the answer there. The reason for that flag was that four normal users [voted to delete the accepted answer in review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5143887). Before the nice edit by Palimundo, [that answer wasn't the best](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24401535/revisions).

That caused the moderator to examine the question itself, and while the question is about a developer tool, it is asking about a potential bug in a beta version of that tool. It used to be standard procedure to close such time-specific questions about beta tools as "too localized", but that close reason was removed a little while ago. Many of these type of questions still get closed because there's some debate as to whether they fit here (although the consensus [seems to now be that they can be appropriate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258504/are-questions-still-on-topic-if-they-solely-pertain-to-beta-software-and-will-li)). I think that was the reasoning here, not that the question about the tool itself was off-topic.

As pointed out, it was [reviewed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/5753093) [three](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/5726649) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/5686052) and in all three cases community members agreed with the close decision. Even if your proposed system for punishing moderators was in place, it would have made no impact here.

If you strongly disagree with a unilateral close vote by a moderator, you can use an "other" flag and explain why you believe a mistake was made in closure. We overturn close votes by each other all the time in response to such arguments, so one moderator's vote isn't the final say on anything. We all have different areas of expertise and different opinions on what is and is not appropriate for the site. We're not afraid to confront others about why they voted to close or delete something on the site.

You can also make an argument on Meta for something to be reopened. You put forth a good enough case that five members of the community did decide to overturn the moderator and reopen the question. I consider this the system working fairly well, and see no need for an additional layer of complexity to be added on top of that.

Comment: Thanks for that - this is constructive and helpful. I just didn't know the system well enough - people should address questions like mine as you did and explain things, rather than spew negativity as some others have done here.

Answer (score 8):

Absolutely not.

You voted (at least, I *hope* you voted) for your moderators. The entire process is completely democratic and transparent, which means that the moderators are people the community as a collective, trusts.

Doubting their decisions on such a regular basis is like putting another locked door behind the locked door in your house. You don't trust your key to be enough, so you need another key to peer review it.

If you feel like a question can and should be reopened, vote or flag it to be reopened (it takes 3,000 reputation to cast a reopen vote).

This specific question made it to the reopen queue 3 times, and was voted to stay closed on all 3 times.

Comment: I'd be willing to bet a _very small_ percentage of users vote for moderators on SO. And I think it's unrealistic to expect them to do so. 

It's very surprising to me that that specific question was voted closed despite 3 re-opens. The system's broken.

Comment: @inorganik: Yes, a very small percentage of users vote for moderators on SO. And I think it's very realistic to expect them to do so, or not bother complaining about how the moderators that they *didn't bother to try and pick* are doing their job badly. Also, whether or not the question is on-topic is up to the community to decide, even if the moderator had made a mistake. It's nothing to make a big deal out of. The question was likely flagged, and the moderator acted on it.

Comment: Fourth time is the charm? I voted to reopen it, and now it's reopened.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Perhaps. Don't get me wrong, I'm pretty sure it's on-topic as well. What bothered me was this bashing against moderators that this post promotes.

Comment: @inorganik I don't know how you can say "the system is broken" based on a single closed question.

Comment: I see mis-moderating on SO a lot. I can't point out more specific examples. To the "moderator bashing" claimed by @SecondRikudo - HAHA. C'mon. Do you need a hug? I'm just saying people make mistakes. Everyone! You. Me. That's not bashing.

Comment: Smells like robo-reviewers to me.

Comment: @inorganik: The solution is simple. Do you see a mismoderation? Fix it. Can't fix it? Flag it. I assure you that *a different* moderator will have a look on it. Feel really really strongly about it? Start a meta post about it. The system is not broken, it works quite nicely.

Comment: @SecondRikudo I can't fix it - I don't have 3k rep.

Comment: You can post in meta at 5 rep, and flag at 15 rep @inorganik. It's extremely easy to fix things around here, provided you are actually willing to fix things and not just whine.

Comment: @Yannis not whining - I didn't know it was possible to overturn a closed question. I don't remember seeing any links that looked hopeful in doing so. This is a suggestion. If you don't like it, you can just disagree instead of calling it whining.