# What to do when a user asks a question about using software far past its prime?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I encountered this in the Triage queue and it made me pause:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38353871/converting-borland-c-to-borland-builder-for-nt

This comment by drescherjm pretty much sums it up.

> You are asking for advice on 20+ year old software that has been
>   obsolete for 15+ years. I have used both of these for years but my
>   memory (of software I used in the 1990s) is not that good. Can't you
>   upgrade to a free modern compiler and IDE?

Searching Meta shows this question, but I don't think it's a duplicate.

[Are questions still on-topic if they solely pertain to beta software and will likely become obsolete?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258504/are-questions-still-on-topic-if-they-solely-pertain-to-beta-software-and-will-li)

That's a question about current software becoming quickly obsolete. As the question implies, if SO banned answers like that, they might as well ban all questions, because technology is so rapidly changing.

This question, however, is about using incredibly obsolete software. To the point that my assessment is that it's highly unlikely that anyone will *ever* want that information ever again.

Is this question on topic for SO? If not, should it be flagged? How?

Comment: It's unlikely to be answered quickly or answerable at all. That doesn't equate unanswerable. However that particular question is clearly too broad.

Comment: The downvote tooltip suggests that not useful is a valid downvote reason.

Comment: @RobertLongson that needs a definition of "not useful". I don't use 99.9% of the programming languages available and thus all questions relating to them are not useful to me, but I'm not going to go on a downvoting spree :)

Comment: Even [60 years is not enough](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068253/edsac-17bit-and-35bit-integers).

Comment: @Gimby Nobody is suggesting going on a spree, voting should be as you find questions. If you see a question and you think it's not going to be useful to anyone else because the software has been dead for 15 years then why do we need to keep that question/answer?

Comment: @Robert because there's a zillion reasons why the question might be useful after all - research, for example. Or nostalgia - somebody running the compiler they learned programming with in an emulator. It's awfully arrogant to want to judge what is useful and what isn't.  Are there no more pressing problems on Stack Overflow that would benefit from our voting?

Comment: @Pekka웃 but it's *your* votes, after all. If *you* don't find it useful, you can downvote it.

Comment: @Pekka웃 if that's what you think, vote accordingly. You need to judge this to make this site a repository of useful questions and answers, if you think it's useful upvote, if not useful downvote, if meh don't vote. If you have a positive or negative opinion and don't vote you're not using the site properly. If you want to vote on something else you can do that too.

Comment: @Robert the question of obsolescence should *not* be subject to up or down voting. I don't go around downvoting questions of a specific language just because I happen to have a negative opinion of it. The question should be closevoted/downvoted based on the fact  that it is *too broad.*

Comment: @Pekka웃 Of course not, Python and R are not dead so questions on them are useful to a large number of people, Borland C++ is however long dead. If you don't care, don't vote.

Comment: The comments on this thread show that ironically, Stackoverflow rules and recommendations suffer from a lack of clarity or precision of definition which an important cause of many the bugs we talk about

Comment: this is solvable with close votes; of which you can have your pick in most cases. **too broad** in this case fits just fine. **recommendations** would be acceptable as well as **no mcve**, since there is no code. If there was code that specifically didn't work it would be **on topic**.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson 
Well, sure, the question itself is really only tangentially related to the question.

Comment: A couple of weeks ago my company had an outage in a production system that was caused by upgrading a server.  Some "old" (under 5 years) software that was written on a now unsupported IDE on an unsupported OS for unsupported hardware had issues with changes to the server.  Fixing it required a one line change in the source code (plus rather a lot of hours working out how to rebuild the development environment).  Replacing the system would cost a couple of million and take weeks/months (solution is deployed to thousands of instances nationwide).  Sometimes there's no choice

Answer (score 106, accepted):

There is no reason to do anything from a community moderation viewpoint.*

The fact that they're using obsolete software can and will be pointed out in the comments.

If, when given that information, the OP *still* wants to use the compiler - for reasons of nostalgia, curiosity, scientific interest, whatever - who are we to stop them?

We don't *know* that the information will be irrelevant to anyone else, even though we may find it likely. The Internet is a big place.

<sub>* = about the *obsolescence* aspect. The question is, of course, now rightfully closed as "too broad."</sub>

Comment: And in some cases, the OP may be modifying a small part of a very large system that was written many years ago and has been running ever since. Think banking, aeronautics, defense.

Comment: @shoover: Despite the fact that my field is in one of those three, I hadn't considered that...
You're right, though I could probably come up with a contrived question that follows this policy but is useless. Of course, it might get downvoted into oblivion despite the best wishes of moderators and high rep users.

Comment: It appears that some teaching institutions in Asia encourage or even insist on the use of the antique Borland systems.  It is far from the first, and unlikely to be the last, time that the problem has occurred in the C and C++ tags.  As you noted, the best thing to do is recommend an upgrade and answer to the best of our ability.  When they seek to do that which is impossible because of the antiquity of the software (which pre-dates the C++98 standard), explain why it's impossible — and advise the upgrade.

Comment: Interesting... [If It Ain't Broke, Don't Fix It: Ancient Computers in Use Today](http://www.pcworld.com/article/249951/computers/if-it-aint-broke-dont-fix-it-ancient-computers-in-use-today.html)

Comment: @shoover "Think banking, aeronautics, defense." ...To me, those seem like the absolute *worst* places to be running outdated software... despite the fact you're almost certainly correct.

Answer (score 30):

Obsolescence is not an off-topic reason.  You can however vote/flag to close if it qualifies for another reason.  In this case, the question sounds too broad, so you can close it for that reason.

Answer (score 12):

The topic of obsolete software, or software far past its prime, or some other analogy for once used technology, is perfectly fine to ask about at Stack Overflow. There is no close reason for obsolete, nor will there ever be I suspect.

The problem with the specific question you show is not that the technology may be obsolete; the problem is that the question is very low quality. Essentially it is asking a yes or no question, with the implication that yes should show how. That is definitely **too broad**, as the answerer would have to create a tutorial for how to port the code or write a library that ported the code.

Either way, it is not a good fit for Stack Overflow because of the type of answer required to solve the problem, not because of out dated software.

Answer (score 11):

There are a lot of valid reasons for asking questions about obsolete software and developer tools, and the answers to those questions may very well be useful to others.  There are many organizations still using applications written in ancient times (by our standards) because they still work, the cost and time involved in retraining employees is prohibitive, and/or there have been massive investments into customization around specific business rules that would be difficult, risky, and/or expensive to migrate to more current systems.

These same organizations may dictate (either out of technical necessity, lack of budget, lack of technical evangelism, or fear of change) the use of similarly ancient tools for maintaining those applications.  Most of us developers find these requirements to be extremely frustrating, but it doesn't mean it doesn't happen more often than we'd like.  I spent the first part of the previous decade maintaining software that was written in FoxPro for DOS.  It certainly wasn't my first choice, but it was my job.

I don't see any reason to start arbitrarily closing questions because *we* hold the personal opinion that the technology is too old to be viable anymore.  IBM still sells a lot of mainframes for a reason.

Answer (score 9):

Good questions regarding old software such as this are on-topic at the recently formed [Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/) site and there's a group of people who can answer them.

You could suggest moving the question there.

Comment: Once Stack Overflow reaches its 20th anniversary, we can start a mass migration of questions over to retrocomputing :p

Comment: Why would you feel compelled to move perfectly good question that may be on topic about programming to retro computing? If it's a programming related question it is on topic on stackoverflow.if it provides the required information about the development environment,platform, etc and has an [mcve] it would be very much on topic no matter how old the software tools are.

Answer (score 8):

There are perfectly legitimate reasons for using an obsolete tech stack.

Old IE versions are a classic case in point (although thankfully becoming less common today), where developers need to be able to support them, even though they know how painfully out of date they are.

Another example I've seen more than once is where an old system that has been performing it's task perfectly for decades is in need of some maintenance, usually due to some external change that affects it. The developers are forced to dust off the source code and the old tech stack and try to work out how to get it all up and running.

The poor unfortunate developers who are forced into this kind of scenario really don't need close votes and sarcastic comments telling them to upgrade when they come here to ask for help.

Comment: But sarcastic comments are one of the most important services that we provide here!